# How to configure Visual Studio's test application

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017

On my PC, unit test execution is not working.
On the PC of a collegue, it is working (he has a different version of Visual Studio 2017 Professional).
So I asked him the result of the output window ("Debug" tab page) when launching a test, and already I see a big difference between his first log line and mine:

My first log line (partially):

```
'testhost.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): ...\mscorlib.dll'. ...
```

His first log line:

```
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): ...\mscorlib.dll'. ...
```

So it seems that his configuration uses the program `vstest.executionengine.x86.exe` for launching unit tests, while my configuration causes the program `testhost.x86.exe` to be used.

I have both programs on my PC (UNIX emulator `find` results):

```
Prompt> find ./ -name "testhost.x86.exe" 2>/dev/null
...
./Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/Common7/IDE/Extensions/TestPlatform/testhost.x86.exe

Prompt> find ./ -name "vstest.executionengine.x86.exe" 2>/dev/null
./Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TestWindow/vstest.executionengine.x86.exe
...
```

How can I modify the configuration of my Visual Studio environment in order for the `vstest.executionengine.x86.exe` to be used for launching unit tests?

Comment: In the meanwhile I've found out that the issue was caused by missing references in the testproject. They have been added now and everything is working fine. I'll try to remove this post. The bounty can't be received anymore.

Comment: This question is [being discussed on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366121/how-to-delete-a-question-with-an-open-bounty)

Comment: As said on Meta: if it turned out to be a version mismatch, just add that as an answer for anybody running into a similar problem ([you will not get your own bounty](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/294808/4042267)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the meanwhile the issue is solved, it was caused by a version mismatch.